# Mounting Encfs Container

Tags: encryption

I have an encfs container in my home directory. I had been using Cryptkeeper to open the container, but since updating to Linux Mint 17 from 16 it's not working any more. Gnome Encfs manager doesn't work either. I've also tried mounting the container from the command line using [these directions](http://tuxtweaks.com/2013/10/encrypted-folders-linux-encfs/), but no luck. The name of my mountpoint is `.rthg_encfs`

I tried the following commands:

`fusermount -u ~/.rthg_encfs`

It came back with: fusermount: entry for /home/fren/.rthg_encfs not found in /etc/mtab

`encfs ~/.rthg ~/rthg`

It came back with: The directory "/home/fren/.rthg/" does not exist. Should it be created? (y,n)

Of course I don't want to create a new container, because I already have one that I want to mount.

Comment: It would really help if you a) provided the exact invocation you're using on the command-line, and b) any messages/outcomes you get from that.

Comment: @tink I made some edits.

Comment: So ... have you considered **encfs ~/.rthg_encfs ~/rthg**? :)

Comment: @tink Tx, that worked! I suppose I'll delete this thread?

Comment: You could. Or I could make it an answer and get some credit ;}

Comment: So that means, `.rthg_encfs` is not your mountpoint, but it's your encrypted "rootdir" (as `man encfs` calls it). `~/rthg` is your mountpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
encfs ~/.rthg_encfs ~/rthg
```